# Which function has the back-button of "pushViewController"?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I want to use programmatically the function of the back-button of the view that was put on the overlay by "pushViewController". I already tried "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated" but it wasnt working.

With other words I simply wanna simulate the click on the back-button to get back to the previous view that pushed the view.

Comment: What view controller did you send the dismiss message? You have to send it to the modal view controller that's on top.

Comment: Are you sure, your code is executed btw? Did you log it? Also, you might want to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`instead. The other one is deprecated.

Comment: you are probably mixing things. You are talking about a back button so I guess you just pushed a view (and did not present a modal view). In that case you just need to call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Thanks, @ Sebrassi's solution works! And yeah, I pushed the view.